# Does Kubernetes take JSON format as input file to create configmap and secret?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have an existing configuration file in JSON format, something like below

```
{
    "maxThreadCount": 10,
    "trackerConfigs": [{
            "url": "https://example1.com/",
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "defaultLimit": 1
        },
        {
            "url": "https://example2.com/",
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "defaultLimit": 1
        }
    ],
    "repoConfigs": [{
        "url": "https://github.com/",
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "type": "GITHUB"
    }],
    "streamConfigs": [{
        "url": "https://example.com/master.json",
        "type": "JSON"
    }]
}
```

I understand that I am allowed to pass key/value pair properties file with --from-file option for configmap and secret creation.

But How about JSON formatted file ? Does Kubernetes take JSON format file as input file to create configmap and secret as well?

```
$ kubectl create configmap demo-configmap --from-file=example.json
```

If I run this command, it said configmap/demo-configmap created. But how can I refer this configmap values in other pod ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you create configmap/secret using `--from-file`, by default the file name will be the key name and content of the file will be the value.

For example, You created configmap will be like

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  test.json: |
    {
        "maxThreadCount": 10,
        "trackerConfigs": [{
                "url": "https://example1.com/",
                "username": "username",
                "password": "password",
                "defaultLimit": 1
            },
            {
                "url": "https://example2.com/",
                "username": "username",
                "password": "password",
                "defaultLimit": 1
            }
        ],
        "repoConfigs": [{
            "url": "https://github.com/",
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "type": "GITHUB"
        }],
        "streamConfigs": [{
            "url": "https://example.com/master.json",
            "type": "JSON"
        }]
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-07T09:03:55Z"
  name: demo-configmap
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "5283"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/demo-configmap
  uid: ce566b36-c141-426e-be30-eb843ab20db6
```

You can mount the configmap into your pod as volume. where the key name will be the file name and value will be the content of the file. like following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: demo-configmap
  restartPolicy: Never
```

When the pod runs, the command ls `/etc/config/` produces the output below:

`test.json`

Comment: Thanks for the help, since I have mounted the file at location /etc/config/test.json. I'd like to read the content of this file from my java app. I can define an env key/value pair, the value is /etc/config/test.json, and call System.getenv().get("key"); to read it. but I  am wondering if there is a way that I can define and call it with System.getProperty() ? so I don't have to change from System.getenv().get() to System.getProperty() in my java app code.

Comment: you can pass the configmap as env variable. like this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables

Comment: Yes, but it's still an Environment variable,  I have to change my java app code to  System.getenv().get() to have it.I'd like to set a Java system property, so I can just call System.getProperty() without updating my app code

Answer (score 2):

Config maps are a container for key value pairs. So, if you create a ConfigMap from a file containing JSON, this will be stored with the file name as key and the JSON as value.

To access such a Config Map from a Pod, you would have to mount it into your Pod as a volume:

[How to mount config maps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution as stated from hoque did not work for me. In may case that app terminated with a very suspect message:

```
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'myapp.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I could see that appsettings.json was deployed but something has gone wrong here. In the end, [this solution](https://dev.to/joshduffney/kubernetes-using-configmap-subpaths-to-mount-files-3a1i) has worked for me (similar, but with some extras):

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: webapp
      image: <my image>
      volumeMounts:
      - name: appconfig
        # "mountPath: /app" only doesn't work (app crashes)
        mountPath: /app/appsettings.json
        subPath: appsettings.json
  volumes:
    - name: appconfig
      configMap:
        name: my-config-map
        # Required since "mountPath: /app" only doesn't work (app crashes)
        items:
        - key: appsettings.json
          path: appsettings.json
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-map
  labels:
    app: swpq-task-02-team5
data:
  appsettings.json: |
    {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue for a couple of days as I wanted to refer a json config file (`config.production.json`) from my local directory into a specific location inside the containers for pod (`/var/lib/ghost`). The below config worked for me. Please note the `mountPath` and `subPath` keys that did the trick for me. The snippet below is of a pod `kind=deployment` shortened for ease of reading ---

```
 spec:
      volumes:
        - name: configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: configmap
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: url
              value: https://www.example.com
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configmap-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/ghost/config.production.json
              subPath: config.production.json
```