# Kubernetes Jobspec Passing Json Args: Why Is This Invalid Yaml And How To Fix?

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to run jobs that call python apps that take dictionaries as parameters.

For example, running it locally might look like this:

```
 python3 examples/test.py '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}'
```

So, in my jobspec I am trying to do this:

```
command: ["/bin/bash","-c"]
args: ["python3 examples/test.py '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}'"]
```

However, I get a yaml error:

```
error: error parsing job.yaml.tmpl: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 18: could not find expected ':'
```

I see in yaml lint that it is not valid.  The only way I have managed to pass yaml validation is to escape every single quote, which is not scalable for hundreds of jobs that users will be running

```
args: 
  - "python3 examples/test.py '{\"school\":\"hello\", \"standard\": \"5\"}'"
```

Why is this not valid yaml and how can I do this without needing to escape every single quote in a given dictionary a user passes in?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to replicate your setup without your code, however below examples should work for you. In Kubernetes Docs - [Run a command in a shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell) you can find information, that all commands should be `wrapped`.

> In some cases, you need your command to run in a shell. For example, your command might consist of several commands piped together, or it might be a shell script. To run your command in a shell, wrap it.

Below you have default syntax

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["command one; command two && command three"]
```

I've changed a bit your command and verified on [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/), all passed.

**Examples with only `/bin/bash` in `command`:**

```
command: 
  - /bin/bash
args: 
  - "-c"
  - "python3 examples/test.py '{\"school\":\"EFG\", \"standard\": \"2\", \"name\": \"abc\", \"city\": \"miami\"}'\"]"

or

command: ["/bin/bash"]
args: ["-c", "python3 examples/test.py", '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}']
```

**Examples with `/bin/bash` and `-c` in `command`:**

```
command: 
  - /bin/bash
  - "-c"
args: 
  - "python3 examples/test.py"
  - "{\"school\":\"EFG\", \"standard\": \"2\", \"name\": \"abc\", \"city\": \"miami\"}"

or

command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
args: ["python3 examples/test.py", '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}']
```

In addition, there was a question about running multiple kubernetes commands in `spec`. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes).

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: No I don't think so.  The goal is to not escape any quotes. Using the examples of separating the json into a separate argument seems to cause the python program to be run without any arguments.  ie- it seems like `python3 examples/test.py` is getting called on its own without the json getting passed in to it

Comment: Regarding the above comment, I tested these two ideas:
`args: ["-c", "python3 examples/test.py", '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}']`

`args: ["python3 examples/test.py", '{"school":"EFG", "standard": "2", "name": "abc", "city": "miami"}']`

Comment: Maybe different approach like using `ConfigMap` with JSON embedded inside literal block scalar? Something like that was already mention in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654051/10347794). [Python docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)